# Powershell Passing Variable to -Filter with Wild Card

Tags: powershell, filter, active-directory

I am having a hard time here on this one and I know its probably a simple syntax problem. I don't know how to pass this variable into the code chunk and have it acknowledged correctly.

```
$user = "Some.Person"
```

This works as I would expect.

```
get-aduser -filter {(Samaccountname -eq $user)}
```

This does not

```
get-aduser -filter {(userprincipalname -like $user*)}
```

tried with variations of `"$user*"`, `"'$user*'"` as well as some others to no avail.

final outcome would be use like follows because we have AD accounts where UPN is different than UserName and I have a whole listing of Username formatted values I need to confirm still exist with active accounts.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {(UserPrincipalName -like "$user*") -or (SamAccountName -eq "$user")} -SearchBase "" -Server "MyServer:3268"
```

Comment: Does this work: `get-aduser -filter {userprincipalname -like "$user*"}`

Comment: @Keith-Hill negative.... No Error or Warning of any kind, just null result. replacing the variable with text works fine. This cmdlet is out of the ActiveDirectory module and the help reference doesn't appear to shed any light example wise on passing a variable with a wild card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange behaviour, this is not THE answer but a turn arround ; personnaly, I use `-LDAPFilter` :

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(userprincipalname=$user*)"
```

The polish notation for the filter is a bit disconcerting at the begining, but here, it's the natural way of filtering using the underlaying protocol LDAP.

```
Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(|(userprincipalname=$user*)(samAccountName=$user))"
```

You can get more information about this syntax in [Search Filter Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you can also get corresponding filters in [About_ActiveDirectory_Filter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh531527%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

---

If you really want to use the `-Filter` syntax you can do the following (I'am not so proud of that):

```
$userstar = "$user*"
Get-ADUser -Filter {(userprincipalname -like $userstar) -or (samAccountName -like $user)}
```

Comment: I will give the ldap filter method a go. Looks pretty standard. Have any idea if there is efficiency more so with one over the other? I am not processing a whole lot of user account queries but just curious.

Comment: In my understandanding the LDAP filter is as efficient as the PowerShell filter, just because I'am quite sure that the PowerShell filter is converted to LDAP filter (which is the native ptotocole)

Comment: Marked as answer, both methods work and I will be sticking with the LDAPFilter approach. Thanks much!

Comment: On another note. Not sure why but when using `-LDAPFilter` and making a query with a value that returns no hit I get an empty object where as with `-Filter` I would get whitespace which was also a challenge to work off.