# Find out if a Security Account Manager (SAM) name is a user or a group

Tags: powershell, active-directory, sam

*edited from original question because the real problem was something unrelated to the question*

I got a list of trustees from NTFS permissions and now I want to expand the groups to show membership. If I have a SAM name like MyDomain\name, there's no indication of whether that is a group or not. The Get-ADobject command has an ObjectClass property which will indicate group or user if this is an Active Directory domain object. One can use:
`Get-ADObject -filter 'SamAccountName -eq "My Users"'` or
`$sam = "My Users"`
`Get-ADObject -filter 'SamAccountName -eq $sam'`
Thanks to JPBlanc who had an alternate form of writing that with a script block and some other suggestions.
And thanks, user2142466. That looks like a good suggestion for my original script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a variavle using :

```
$sam = "My Users"
Get-ADObject -Filter {(SamAccountName -eq $sam)}
```

But I agree that using vars in `-Filter` sometimes results in strange behaviours with vars ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19171597/608772)), so I prefer to use `-LDAPFilter`.

```
Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(SamAccountName =$user)"
```

Be careful the -LDAPFilter use polish notation for the filter, it's a bit disconcerting at the begining, but here, it's the natural way of filtering using the underlaying protocol LDAP.

You can get more information about this syntax in [Search Filter Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you can also get corresponding filters in [About_ActiveDirectory_Filter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh531527%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I am  guessing you are getting an array of trustees. (i.e User,Group,user,user,Group). So if you get a group then you want to pull the members from it too?

So I would look to see if it is a group, like how you are doing first and then pulling those members out of it. Add it to an another array which will contain every single user for your NTFS permissions.

```
$arraytrustees

#Create a blank Array

$NTFSUsers =@()
for each ($object in $arraytrustees){

$ObjectClass = (Get-ADObject -filter {SamAccountName -eq $object}).ObjectClass

  If ($ObjectClass -eq "group"){
  $AdGroupUsers = (Get-ADGroupMember -identity $object).SamAccountName
  $NTFSUsers = $NTFSUsers + $AdGroupUsers
   }else{
    $NTFSUsers = $NTFSUsers + $ojbect
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I received a list and was asked to determine whether the objects were users or group, and I came up with this.  It worked!

```
cls
$Users = @()
$Groups = @()
$list = Get-Content z:\pcm.txt
Foreach ($o in $list)
{
$ObjectClass = (Get-ADObject -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $o}).ObjectClass
  If ($ObjectClass -eq "User")
  {
  $U = Get-ADUser -Properties * -Identity $o
  $User = "" | Select FullUserName, LoginID, Description
  $User.FullUserName = $U.DisplayName
  $User.LoginID = $U.SamAccountName
  $User.Description = $U.description
  $Users += $User
  }
 Else
 {
 If ($ObjectClass -eq "Group")
 {
 $G = Get-ADGroup -Properties * -Identity $o
 $Group = "" | Select GroupName, Description
 $Group.GroupName = $G.Name
 $Group.Description = $G.Description
 $Groups += $Group
 }
}
}
$Users | Export-Csv z:\Users.csv -NoTypeInformation
$Groups | Export-Csv z:\Groups.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

I was asked to list all members of the groups, along with their ID,        Name, and Description as well, so I added a couple of lines.

```
cls
$Users = @()
$Groups = @()
$list = Get-Content z:\pcm2.txt
Foreach ($o in $list)
{
$ObjectClass = (Get-ADObject -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $o}).ObjectClass
  If ($ObjectClass -eq "User")
  {
  $U = Get-ADUser -Properties * -Identity $o
  $User = "" | Select FullUserName, LoginID, Description
  $User.FullUserName = $U.DisplayName
  $User.LoginID = $U.SamAccountName
  $User.Description = $U.description
  $Users += $User
  }
 Else
 {
 If ($ObjectClass -eq "Group")
 {
 $G = Get-ADGroup -Properties * -Identity $o
 $GM = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $G.name -Recursive | Get-ADUser -Properties *
 Foreach ($gmember in $GM)
 {
 $Group = "" | Select GroupName, GroupDescription, GroupMemberName, GroupMemberLoginID, GroupMemberDesc
 $Group.GroupName = $G.Name
 $Group.GroupDescription = $G.Description
 $Group.GroupMemberName = $gmember.Name
 $Group.GroupMemberLoginID = $gmember.SamAccountName
 $Group.GroupMemberDesc = $gmember.Description
 $Groups += $Group
 }
}
}
}
$Users | Export-Csv z:\PCMUsers.csv -NoTypeInformation
$Groups | Export-Csv z:\PCMGroups.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work for you:

```
    Function Get-Folder($initialDirectory="")

{
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms")|Out-Null

    $foldername = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $foldername.Description = "Select a folder"
    $foldername.rootfolder = "MyComputer"
    $foldername.SelectedPath = $initialDirectory

    if($foldername.ShowDialog() -eq "OK")
    {
        $folder += $foldername.SelectedPath
    }
    return $folder
}

$Folder = Get-Folder


$ACEs = (Get-Acl $Folder).Access

$number = $aces.Count
$allusers = @()

foreach($ACE in $ACEs)

    {
        
    $ID = $ACE.IdentityReference
    $Right = $ACE.FileSystemRights

    $strID = $id.ToString()
    $Object = $strID.split("\")[1]
    $location = $strID.split("\")[0]
    $DomainName = (Get-ADDomain).name
        
    if($location -eq $DomainName)
        {
        $ObjectClass = (Get-ADObject -filter {SamAccountName -eq $object}).ObjectClass

       If ($ObjectClass -eq "group")
            {
            $usernames = (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupname -recursive).name
            foreach ($username in $usernames)
                    {
                    $UserDetail = New-Object system.object
                    $UserDetail | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $username
                    $UserDetail | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name Acecess -Value $Right
                    $userdetail | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name ADGroup -Value $groupname
                    $allusers+= $UserDetail
                    }
            }
        else
            {

            $UserDetail = New-Object system.object
            $UserDetail | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $object
            $UserDetail | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name Acecess -Value $Right
            $userdetail | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name ADGroup -Value "No Group"
            $allusers+= $UserDetail
            }
        }
        
    }

    
$allusers | Out-GridView
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**