# Powershell ActiveDirectory module Variable with wildcard not working

Tags: powershell, module, active-directory

Why doesn't the below get-adcomputer commandline return any results?  It's really irritating when cmdlets don't accomodate powershell syntax.  At least that's what it looks like is happening here.  If I do a write-output, it displays exactly what I want to be inserted in the commandline.  However, when I go to use it with the get-adcomputer cmdlet, no results are returned.

```
PS: C:\> $Variable = "88FF"

PS: C:\> write-output "*$($Variable)*"
*88FF*

PS: C:\> Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like "*$($Variable)*"} -Property * 
PS: C:\> 
PS: C:\> Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like "*88FF*"} -Property * 
computer1
computer2
computer3
```

I've tried a bunch of different variants... including even adding literal quotes to the variable by escaping them.  I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out something that should take less than 10 seconds to do.

```
PS: C:\> $Variable = "`"*888FF*`""
PS: C:\> $Variable
"*88FF*"
PS: C:\> PS: C:\> Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like $Variable} -Property * 
PS: C:\>
```

Edit:  I've also tried below variant with same exact result:

```
PS: C:\> Get-ADComputer -Filter {Name -like '*$Variable*'} -Property * 
PS: C:\>
```

Comment: Is `-Property *` a valid switch/argument?  This http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617192.aspx seems to indicate the valid switch is `-Properties`

Comment: @inquisitor yes -property is just fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Powershell Passing Variable to -Filter with Wild Card](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171597/powershell-passing-variable-to-filter-with-wild-card)

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -like '*$Variable*'" -Property *
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty lame, it looks like this is one of the many limitations of the Powershell Active-Directory module that comes with Windows.  I wasn't doing anything wrong in my original attempts.  I ended up having pipeline the output to where{ } to filter it items.

```
Get-ADComputer -properties Name, OperatingSystem -Filter *| ?{$_.name -like "*$($Variable)*"} |ft Name, OperatingSystem -Wrap -Auto
```

Comment: It *wasn't* a limitation of the ActiveDirectory module from Microsoft, until recently.  This behavior occurs when using RSAT for Server 2012 R2 under PowerShell 4.0 on Windows 8.1.  When I upgraded, this problem broke a bunch of my scripts.  I (and others) have posted the problem on TechNet forums, but only gotten several "me too" responses.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$myvar="*888FF*"
get-adcomputer -filter {name -like $myvar} -property *
```

It's really annoying, you would expect this to work but -filter just has some weird parsing rules internally I guess

```
$myvar="888FF"
get-adcomputer -filter {name -like "*$myvar*"} -property *
```

Answer (score 0):

Shay's solution works beautifully (at least on v4)

I also found out that LDAPFilters will work too!

get-adcomputer -LDAPFilter "(&(name=$name*)(operatingsystem=*server*))"